# How is silicon for ICs produced?

Tags: fabrication

You hear in grade school that the input to silicon foundries is sand and ICs come out the other side, but you never much more about the refining process or what is actually involved in extracting silicon from the overall sand composition.

How is silicon for foundries sourced and/or extracted from sand?  Does it come from a special beach in an exotic location?  From the nearest creek to a foundry?

Comment: http://www.hpquartz.com/2009/05/24/how-sand-is-transformed-into-silicon-chips/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridgman–Stockbarger_technique

Comment: https://youtu.be/qm67wbB5GmI also,  question is way too broad.

Comment: The actual boule is grown from commercially available material extracted industrially from a quarry. The only requirement is purity, achieved with traditional techniques (physical sorting, boiling out impurities, chemical extraction). The source is not important, silicon is silicon, But it is not a single crystal (lattice structure). At a fab this industrial material is melted down, and put in very controlled conditions to grow a single uninterrupted crystal

Comment: Sometimes, silicon comes from a bottle \$SiH_4\$ as a gas. Nasty.

Comment: @glen_geek I worked at FABs designing/implementing closed loop temp controls. Silane was nasty. IBM showed a video placing a 1/2-inch steel walled cabinet on an airport runway with a small canister of silane equipped with a remote controlled "dial-a-leak" feature. The high speed video showed the cabinet on frame 7152. And showed *nothing* at frame 7153. Completely gone. Pieces were found 1/4-mile away. Silane, arsine (TLV=50ppbv), and phosphine/phosphane were my favorites. (Fed-ex guy delivered an arsine canister once -- by hand -- had no idea what was in it! We kept it in a triple-vault.)

Comment: Czochralski crystal pulling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They start with a seed crystal and grow it into a long ingot by pulling it out of molten silicon.  Then they slice the ingot into thin wafers which move on to the IC production phase.

Try reading this on how they process silicon from sand:
https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/manufacturing-si-cells/refining-silicon

> **Metallurgical Grade Silicon**
>
> Silica is the dioxide form of silicon (SiO2) and occurs naturally in the form of quartz. While beach sand is also largely quartz, the most common raw material for electronic grade is high purity quartz rock.  Ideally the silica has low concentrations of iron, aluminum and other metals. The silica is reduced (oxygen removed) through a reaction with carbon in the form of coal, charcoal and heating to 1500-2000 °C in an electrode arc furnace.
>
> SiO2 + C → Si + CO2
>
> The resulting silicon is metallurgical grade silicon (MG-Si). It is 98% pure and is used extensively in the metallurgical industry.
> An even greater production of silicon is in the form of ferrosilicon that is manufactured using a similar process to that described above but is done in the presence of iron. Ferrosilicon is used extensively in metals manufacturing. In 2013 the total production of silicon was 7.6 million tonnes and 80 % of that was in the form of ferrosilicon.

> **Electronic Grade Silicon**
>
> A small amount of the metallurgical grade silicon is further refined for the semiconductor industry. Powdered MG-Si is reacted with anhydrous HCl at 300 °C in a fluidized bed reactor to form SiHCl3
>
> Si + 3HCl → SiHCl3 + H2
>
> During this reaction impurities such as Fe, Al, and B react to form their halides (e.g. FeCl3, AlCl3, and
> BCl3). The SiHCl3 has a low boiling point of 31.8 °C and distillation is used to purify the SiHCl3 from the
> impurity halides. The resulting SiHCl3 now has electrically active impurities(such as Al, P, B, Fe, Cu or Au) of less than 1 ppba.
>
> Finally, the pure SiHCl3 is reacted with hydrogen at 1100°C for ~200 – 300 hours to produce a very pure form of silicon.
>
> SiHCl3 + H2 →Si + 3 HCl
>
> The reaction takes place inside large vacuum chambers and the silicon is deposited onto thin polysilicon rods (small grain size silicon) to produce high-purity polysilicon rods of diameter 150-200mm. The process was first developed by Siemens in the 60's and is often referred to as the Siemens process.
>
> The resulting rods of semiconductor grade silicon are broken up to form the feedstock for the crystallisation process. The production of semiconductor grade silicon requires a lot of energy. Solar cells can tolerate higher levels of impurity than integrated circuit fabrication and there are proposals for alternative processes to create a "solar-grade" silicon.

I hope this answers your question.